# I'd like to add a a conformation button to my Delete button in Form mode in laravel

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, I'd like my delete button to add a confirm option to it:

```
{!!Form::open(['action'=>['PostsController@destroy', $posts->id], 'method'=> 'POST', 'class' => 'float-right'])!!}
    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
    {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

This is the code in which I would like to add a confirmation popup which would ask you to confirm if you want to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace this to your button.

```
{!!Form::open(['action'=>['PostsController@destroy', $posts->id], 'method'=> 'DELETE', 'class' => 'float-right'])!!}
     {!! Form::button('Delete', ['type'=>'submit','value'=>'delete','class'=>'btn btn-danger','onclick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure?')"]) !!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet I'm always using in my projects. It's a default web browser alert pop-up. It creates a hidden form and appends the ID of the property you want to delete to it.

```
<div class="pl-1">
    <button type="button" name="button"
            onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')){ $('form#delete-{{$obj->id}}').submit(); }"
            class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete
    </button>
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['your_route.destroy',$obj->id], 'class' => 'hidden', 'id'=>"delete-".$obj->id]) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```